# What is the fastest way to write large amount of data from BigQuery to Google Sheets using AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am trying to import about 30,000 rows with 10 Columns each of data from BigQuery to Google Sheets using AppScript. I found [this github link](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/advanced/bigquery.gs) which has a function runQuery() for writing data from BigQuery to Google sheets. But it takes around 90 secs to do so. Is there a faster way to achieve the same?

Comment: To debug, it is helpful to run only a part of the function gradually iadding code - to see which step is the most time consuming.  You have the statement `sleepTimeMs *= 2;` which continues doubling the sleeping time as long as the data is not fully loaded.  Apart from loading the data from Big query, writing it with `setValues(data)` can be also time consuming - depending on the amount of data. In general the code will run faster if you reduce calls to any service including BigQuery and SpreadsheetApp. See Best practices: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices

Comment: My first reaction is that 90 seconds to populate 300,000 cells is not too shabby. But I'd take a look at the Execution transcript to see where the time is being occupied; and as suggested by @ziganotschka, I'd export 5,000 rows, 10,000, 15,000, etc to see whether a different on volume is reflected in execution time.

Comment: @ziganotschka Thanks! I did reduce the calls to services, another thing that was taking time was formatting of data(background color, font, etc) that I was trying to do in my code.